# How to sync AWS S3 bucket with a directory and don't keep old version

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, synchronization, aws-cli

I want to sync a directory in my S3 bucket and delete files that are in the destination, that are not in the source.

I try this command but, the files that are only in destination was keep.

```
aws s3 sync my-directory/ s3://my-bucket
```

Answer (score 6):

I found the solution [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html), I just add `--delete`.

```
aws s3 sync my-directory/ s3://my-bucket --delete
```